# Pandas groupby agg nunique many columns

Tags: pandas

DataFrame has got three columns. I would like to implement function agg nunique after groupby and take two columns.

```
    d = {'isin_code': pd.Series([xs, ru, xs, ru, xs], index=[1,2,3,4,5]), 'inn': pd.Series([111, 111, 222, 333, 111], index=[1,2,3,4,5], 'number': pd.Series([Nan, 001, Nan, Nan, 001], index=[1,2,3,4,5])
    
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(d)

df1['inn'] = df1['inn'].astype(str)
df1['number'] = df1['number'].astype(str)
**df1['col4'] = df1['inn'] + df1['number']**
d1 = df1.groupby(by=['isin_code'], as_index=False).agg({'col4': pd.Series.nunique}) 

**it's work, but so primal...**

DF = pd.merge(df1, d1, how='left', on='isin_code')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.cat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.cat.html) for join columns and then for new column [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
s = df1['inn'].astype(str).str.cat(df1['number'].astype(str))
df1['count'] = s.map(s.value_counts())
print (df1)
  isin_code  inn number  count
1        xs  111    NaN      1
2        ru  111    001      2
3        xs  222    NaN      1
4        ru  333    NaN      1
5        xs  111    001      2
```

Comment: (111 + Nan) not equal (111 + 1.0)
111 count 1, 111 1.0 count 1 with groupby isin_code. Not good example, after run we will have count 1 for each

Comment: @Alpha2020 - Not understand, can you add expected ouput?

Comment: `111     NaN` + `222     NaN` + `111     1.0` is `3` for `xs` and `111     1.0` + `333     NaN` is `2` for `ru`

Comment: d = {'isin_code': pd.Series([ru, ru, ru, xs, xs], index=[1,2,3,4,5]), 'inn': pd.Series([111, 111, 111, 222, 111], index=[1,2,3,4,5], 'number': pd.Series([001, 001, Nan, Nan, 001], index=[1,2,3,4,5])
   
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(d)

After groupby 
ru 111 001 count 2
ru 111 Nan count 1
xs 222 Nan count 1
xs 111 001 count 1

Comment: @Alpha2020 - Can you check now?